# Unicode translation

Tags: python

I have a database of texts, some of which contain unconverted hex codes:

```
import pandas as pd

example = pd.DataFrame({"content": ["Zwischen den Parteien ist unstreitig, dass Sch&#228;den nur an der T aufgetreten sind, die der besonderen Belastung durch den B&#252;rostuhl ausgesetzt ist.",
                                       "Die aufgetretenen Besch&#228;digungen seien auschlie&#223;lich  darauf zur&#252;ckzuf&#252;hren, dass an der Schadensstelle der B&#252;rostuhl mit kleinen R&#228;dern unter Belastung hin und her bewegt werde.",
                                       "Der Kl&#228;gerin steht wegen angeblicher M&#228;ngel an dem Fu&#223;boden kein Zur&#252;ckbehaltungsrecht zu."]})
```

The encoding to utf-8 did not solve the problem and since I have no overview of all possible codes in the texts, I simply created a complete unicode dictionary:

```
import html

def generate_unicode_dictionary(start, end):
    unicode_dict = {}
    for code_point in range(start, end + 1):
        character = chr(code_point)
        html_entity = html.escape(character, quote=False)
        unicode_dict["&#"+str(code_point)+";"] = html_entity
    return unicode_dict

unicode_dictionary = generate_unicode_dictionary(1, 10000)
```

Since the database consists of 200k+ texts, some of which are significantly longer than the example given here, a loop like:

```
def translate_text(text):
    for key, value in unicode_dictionary.items():
        text = text.replace(key, value)
    return text

example["content"] = example["content"].apply(translate_text)
```

(...) takes far too long to execute.

What could be a more efficient approach?

Comment: `html.unescape` should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The proper solution

This kind of conversion is very common, and it is directly supported by the Python standard library's [html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html) module.
You can simply do

```py
example["content"] = example["content"].apply(html.unescape)
```

which is way more efficient.

#### Doing your own implementation

You can also change your implementation of `translate_text` to be more efficient.
I would recommend to use the `html.unescape` function instead,
but it might be instructive to see how `translate_text` could be optimized.

Right now, your algorithm is

```
for every character:  (there are lots)
   find all occurrences and replace them
```

A more efficient approach is:

```
for every occurrence:   (requires searching the text just once)
    replace it according to the dictionary (efficient lookup)
```

For example, you could separate the text into segments between `&` characters.
The escaped characters are at the beginning of each segment (except the first one).

```py
def translate_text(text):
    # (not recommended - use html.unescape instead)
    segments = text.split('&')
    result_parts = [segments[0]]
    for segment in segments[1:]:
        code, _, rest = segment.partition(';')
        result_parts.append(unicode_dictionary[f'&{code};'] + rest)
    return ''.join(result_parts)
```

Not sure if this captures all the cases, but it should get the idea across.